# Animating a scene using OpenGL 3 in C

Tags: c, opengl, animation, translate-animation

I am creating an small animation film using OpenGL 3 and implementing it in visual studio community 2015. I am trying to make an animation of a dinosaur moving to the right at least in the first but I cannot make it animate somehow.

Here is my main:

```
#include "glut.h"
#include "globaldeclare.h"
#include "dino.h"
#include "scene1.h"
#include "scene1_animation.h"
#include <math.h>

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 204.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 500, 0, 500);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

}

void myIdle() {
    frame++;
    scene1_dino_idle();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Animation happens here
    if (scene_counter == 1) {
        scene1();
        scene1_animation();
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1300, 800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Walking with dinosaur");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(myIdle);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0; 
}
```

This is where animation happens for scene1 (but it's not happening.) :)

```
void scene1_dino_idle() {
    //idle
    if (dino_slidey > 0 && dino_count == 1) dino_movey = 1;
    if (dino_movey == 1 && dino_count == 1) dino_slidey -= 2;//1
    if (dino_slidey < -30 && dino_count == 1) dino_movey = 0;
    if (dino_movey == 0 && dino_count == 1) dino_slidey += 2;//1

    if (dino_slidex > 1000 && dino_count == 1) { dino_movex = 1; dino_count = 2; dinoleg_count = 2; }
    if (dino_movex == 1 && dino_count == 1) dino_slidex -= 6;//4
    if (dino_slidex < -1600 && dino_count == 1) dino_movex = 0;
    if (dino_movex == 0 && dino_count == 1) dino_slidex += 6;//4
}

void scene1_dino_animation() {
    //moving to the right
    glPushMatrix();
    if (dino_count == 1) {
        glTranslatef(dino_slidex, dino_slidey, 0);
        glTranslatef(0, 100, 0);
        glScalef(0.6, 0.6, 1);
    }
    glScalef(dinoR_lost, dinoR_lost, 0);
    dino();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void scene1_animation() {
    scene1_dino_animation();
}
```

My global variables
    //frame counter
    int frame, scene_counter = 1;

```
//dino animation
float dino_movex, dino_movey, dino_count, dino_slidex, dino_slidey, dinoR_lost, dinoL_lost;

//dino leg
float dinoleg_angle = 0, dinoleg_move_x, dinoleg_move_y, dinoleg_count = 0;
```

I have done drawing the scene but I can't animate it. It seems to me that I have done right in the animation and maybe somewhere in my idle function does not allow me to make it work. I tried everything but I am not able to make it work and I don't know really where is the problem. Please let me know what is the main issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mentioned you are using OpenGL 3… however it looks you are using deprecated fixed pipeline functions there...

Comment: @rlam12 Is it? Can you tell me which one? I am new to opengl.

Comment: I'm no expert neither, but I can recognize `glTranslatef` `glMatrixMode` and some other functions that are on their way to be removed from the standard, OpenGL 3 uses shaders and customs matrices for everything but I cannot really tell what is wrong with your code, again, no expert. Good luck and Happy New Year!

Comment: Enable compilation warnings to ensure you are not shadowing global variables. Or avoid global variables completely.

Comment: @iharob I'm quite new to C language. May I know what you mean by enable compilation warnings?

Comment: `int main(int argc, char **argv)` is legal C. Some favor `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, however. Enabling warnings is good advise, however.

Comment: Have you viewed ***[this simple animation](http://math.hws.edu/bridgeman/courses/324/s06/doc/opengl.html#animation)***  using OpenGL?  `glutPostRedisplay()` and `glViewPort()` jumped out as particularly interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to make it work. In some scenes that I've drawn, there was only a dino but it doesn't move so I removed the `dino()` from my `scene1()` from scene1.h . It went missing after that, but I noticed some dot moving (I don't where did that came from). Now I fixed it by adding the `glutPostRedisplay()` in `scene1_dino_idle()` function. Then I remove this code `glScalef(dinoR_lost, dinoR_lost, 0);` so the dino appears. Thank you all for helping. Happy new year.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that most of the variables named are global. Since you didn't show us initial values, I'll assume they're all zero (except `scene_counter` and `dino_count`; nothing happens if either of them is zero), and step through a few iterations. (Please excuse the crowded layout of this trace.) These are the values at the entrance to each call to `scene1_dino_idle()`:

```
  scene_counter   dino_movey   dino_slidey  dinoleg_count
frame  | dino_count | dino_movex | dino_slidex   |
  |    |      |     |      |     |      |        |
  1    1*     1*    0      0     0      0        0
  2    1      1     0      0     2      6        0
  3    1      1     1      0     0     12        0
  4    1      1     1      0    -2     18        0
  5    1      1     1      0    -4     24        0
. . .
  f    1      1     1      0 (f-3)*-2 (f-1)*6    0
. . .
 18    1      1     1      0   -30    102        0
 19    1      1     0      0   -30    108        0
 20    1      1     0      0   -28    114        0
. . .
```

Judging from this little trace, it seems that if you're having a problem, it's because `scene_counter` or `dino_count` (or both) are zero. Another possibility is that you're having scope problems with your global variables; if there's a typo somewhere in your declarations C might be treating one or more of them as local variables. (In some versions of C, variables that are not explicitly declared will default to `int`.)

Without your headers, we can't tell what's wrong.

Since some debuggers get along with graphics code poorly, you might consider adding debug code to trace your variables into a file, just like I did manually above.

Best I can tell without compiling it myself and trying to guess what you left out, the OpenGL code is OK.

Comment: Glad you asked. I have provided the global variable just now.

Comment: So what you're seeing is your dinosaur image, but it's not moving?

Comment: Another idea: if you add trace-to-file code, spit out time stamps too. You might also open-write-close the trace file each time, so you can view the file while the program is active.